# Flutter/Dart:How to extract email and phone number from a string in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I extract phone and email information from a description field in flutter

here is an example text

```
 Good to know you!<br/><br/> <br/>Apply online today! 
    If you have any questions please contact fname@lname@company.com<br/>theUser will reach out if we believe you would be a good fit.<br/><br/>
<br>111-222-3333</br>
```

I would like to get the phone#(111-222-3333) and email(fname@lname@company.com)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use String.Split("Your regex")

For the phone number please check this

[Flutter Dart: How to extract a number from a string using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618776/flutter-dart-how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-using-regex)

and for email here's email rejex
use this package https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator

Comment: No, that is not a valid email regex, and will fail on valid email addresses. The *shortest* regex that can match valid email (not counting nested comments) is at http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html, or you can use the one at https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator because it builds up that string from pieces.

Answer (score 2):

```
final mailPattern = r"\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b";
final regEx = RegExp(mailPattern, multiLine: true);
final obtainedMail = regEx.allMatches(text.toString()).map((m) => m.group(0)).join(' ');
```

Use this code as a reference.

`text` is a list which i converted into a long string by writing `text.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for phone numbers starting with +country code detection in a multiline string.

```
\b[+]*[(]{0,1}[6-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.0-9]*\b
```