# how to extract numbers from string in dart language

Tags: regex, string, dart, numbers

I want to extract only numbers from a string in flutter framework by using dart language.

for example in this string.
String str = 'abc3def 4 ghi5 jkl 6mno0 pqrs2';

result should be like this = 345602;

I tried many regular expressions like [a-zA-Z], +/d +/D ^[0-9] but none of them work.

here a piece of code that I am working one, as in my code showing I want to make every character except numbers and convert them to '',

as Reminder I only want to extract numbers.

```
I want to extract only numbers from a string in flutter framework by using dart language.
```

for example in this string.
String str = 'abc3def 4 ghi5 jkl 6mno0 pqrs2';

result should be like this = 345602;

I tried many regular expressions like [a-zA-Z], +/d +/D ^[0-9] but none of them work.

here a piece of code that I am working one, as in my code showing I want to make every character except numbers and convert them to '',

as Reminder I only want to extract numbers.

```
for (TextBlock block in readText.blocks) {
  //  if (block.text.length == 14) {
  setState(() {
    texts.add(block.text.replaceAll(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"), ''));
  });
  print('$count$texts');
  count++;
  // }
}
```

Comment: To match a non-digit char, all you need is `[^0-9]`

Comment: This is a duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618776/flutter-dart-how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-using-regex.