# Dart - Extract number from list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a List that contains lottery numbers
[List image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVUmm.jpg)

How can I separate number and text, and after that list them in the below list: for example:

```
  List<String> n = ["ABC23", "21A23", "12A312","32141A"];
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should give a better example of your case and a desired result, because your image and explanation is very basic and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using forEach like below:

```
List<String> n = ["23", "2123", "12312","32141"];
n.forEach((element) => 
    print(element)
);
```

And to separate number and text you can use the following code:

```
const text = '''
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the 123.456 printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an 12:30 unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
23.4567
type specimen book. It has 445566 survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
''';
final intRegex = RegExp(r'\s+(\d+)\s+', multiLine: true);
final doubleRegex = RegExp(r'\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+', multiLine: true);
final timeRegex = RegExp(r'\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s+', multiLine: true);
void main() {
  print(intRegex.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0)));
  print(doubleRegex.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0)));
  print(timeRegex.allMatches(text).map((m) => m.group(0)));
}
```

Please refer to this link for more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53618776/flutter-dart-how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-using-regex).

Comment: My list contains text bro! 
List<String> n = ["AA23", "BB2123", "12312 - 21231","32141"];

Comment: Can you explain more, please? because I think it is work for you.

Comment: I just want to extract the number, not text inside every single String of List

Answer (score 1):

To do something with each element:

```
List<String> n = ["23", "2123", "12312","32141"];
n.forEach((element) {
    int number = int.parse(element);
    ...
  }
);
```

To do create list of ints:

```
List<String> n = ["23", "2123", "12312","32141"];
final intList = n.map((element) => int.parse(element)).toList();
```